# How to avoid special character using python regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to extract variables from following string (i.e. names surrounded by ' ')

Case1:

```
string = r"RESPONSE(1, -2.532 + 0.779*(LN('Loss_Ratio')) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_Zero'="No"),2.261,0.0) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_children'="Si"),0.307,0.0))"
```

when I apply

```
all_variables = list(set(re.findall("'([^']*)'", string)))
```

I get correct results :

```
all_variables = ['Loss_Ratio','POL_Zero','POL_children']
```

But Case 2 (when *POL_Zero* modality changed)

```
string = r"RESPONSE(1, -2.532 + 0.779*(LN('Loss_Ratio')) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_Zero'="Nos' conditional"),2.261,0.0) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_children'="Si"),0.307,0.0))"
```

The same regex produces wrong result. How can I still obtain correct result in case2 as well?

**Note** that there can be no single or double quotes inside the names.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a non-word boundary - [`r"\B'([^']*)'\B"`](https://regex101.com/r/p8a4Lc/1) - for "whole non-word" searches? Or do you want to match these strings after `(` only  - [`r"\('([^']*)'"`](https://regex101.com/r/p8a4Lc/2)? Can there be `"` inside `'...'`? If not, use `"""'([^"']*)'"""`

Comment: Or maybe restrict to your two particular cases and match (but don't capture) `=` or `)` after the second `'`: `"('([^']*)')(?:[\)=])"`

Comment: Dave, please specify your requirements, as your current question sounds too broad.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I am sorry but your solution to use """'([^"']*)'""" solved the issue I was facing. I am just trying more combinations to make it more robust and put yours in an answer and accept it. yours is the best one I have got so far in my tries

Comment: Once you are sure it is what you need, let me know, I will post with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution to detect text defined inside ' works irrespective of internal apostrophe. Tried several cases , works perfectly

Comment: So, which one should I post? `"""'([^"']*)'"""`?

Comment: yes thats the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may leverage the fact that your single quoted strings cannot contain neither single nor double quotes.

Only in this situtation,

```
"""'([^"']*)'"""
```

regex will work as expected. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kg1k2L/1).

Here,

- `'` - matches a single quote
- `([^"']*)` - Group 1 (if you are using `re.findall', only this part will be present in the output): zero or more (`*`) chars other than`"`and`'`(`[^'"]`)
- `'` - closing single quote.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/jEykBl):

```
import re
s = """RESPONSE(1, -2.532 + 0.779*(LN('Loss_Ratio')) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_Zero'="No"),2.261,0.0) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_children'="Si"),0.307,0.0))

RESPONSE(1, -2.532 + 0.779*(LN('Loss_Ratio')) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_Zero'="Nos' conditional"),2.261,0.0) +SELECT(INDEX_FIRST_TRUE('POL_children'="Si"),0.307,0.0))"""
print(re.findall(r"""'([^"']*)'""", s))
# => ['Loss_Ratio', 'POL_Zero', 'POL_children', 'Loss_Ratio', 'POL_Zero', 'POL_children']
```